# How to install Tensorflow with correct compiletime on Mac OS High Sierra?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, installation, conda, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to install Tensorflow on my computer (running Mas OS High Sierra). I don't have a lot of experience with Python and Anaconda, but I tried (following the advice on Anaconda Cloud):

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Everything worked fine and I had to install also a bunch of other packages. So far so good. However, now I'm on Jupiter Notebook trying to import Tensorflow (version 1.4) and it returns the following warning:

[image]

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem per se (it's just a warning). The binary on conda-forge was build using Python 3.5. You could try to install it via `pip` instead of `conda`.

The only other alternative would be to build Tensorflow from source: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources

Comment: Building from source would also have the benefit of higher performance. If you run a tensorflow program for the first time, you probably get more warnings that your computer would benefit from instructions like SSE4.1 SSE4.2, AVX, AVX2 and FMA. When you build from source, you can configure your installation to take more advantage of your CPU. I could also provide a binary that uses those exact instructions and was build using Python 3.6 if you don't want to build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @max. I tried installing using pip3 but it showed me the exactly same warning. Although, everything seems to run fine. I'm still not worried by performance issues since I'm still learning about Deep Learning and Tensor Flow, so we a rookie in town. Anyways, thanks a lot!